# rotate sprite in CubicBezierCurveMoveModifier

Tags: android, andengine

I can rotate my sprite with the path modifier with correct angle when it's moving. To achieve this i use **setRotation**() inside **onPathWaypointStarted()** method from IPathModifierListener.

```
PathModifier aModifier = new PathModifier(finishTime, aPath,
            new IPathModifierListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPathWaypointStarted(
                        PathModifier pPathModifier, IEntity pEntity,
                        int pWaypointIndex) {

                    switch (pWaypointIndex) {
                    case 0:

                        setRotation(270 + getAngle(xCur1, xCur2, x1, x2));

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        setRotation(270 + getAngle(x1, x2, x3, x4));

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        setRotation(270 + getAngle(x3, x4, x5, x6));

                        break;
                    case 3:

                        setRotation(270 + getAngle(x5, x6, x7, x8));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        setRotation(270 + getAngle(x7, x8, x9, x10));

                        break;

                    case 5:
                        setRotation(270 + getAngle(x9, x10, x11, x12));
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        setRotation(270 + getAngle(x11, x12, x13, x14));
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onPathWaypointFinished(
                        PathModifier pPathModifier, IEntity pEntity,
                        int pWaypointIndex) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPathStarted(PathModifier pPathModifier,
                        IEntity pEntity) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPathFinished(
                        final PathModifier pPathModifier,
                        final IEntity pEntity) {

                    ResourcesManager.getActivity().runOnUpdateThread(
                            new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    unregisterEntityModifier(pPathModifier);

                                }
                            });

                }
            });
```

My getAngle is below

```
    private synchronized float getAngle(float startx, float starty,
        float targetx, float targety) {

    double angle1 = Math.atan2(targety - starty, targetx - startx);
    float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(angle1);
    // Log.e("getAngle", "getAngle" + angle);
    return angle;
}
```

But when I wanna use CubicBezierCurveMoveModifier to move wuite smoothly, i can't find any Listener like IPathModifierListener. So I can't rotate the sprite with correct angle.

Any Idea.

My object:

[image]

Comment: can't solved the issue. any one here, to help?

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party with this and probably found a solution already, but I just came across this issue and whipped this up.

I don't see any reason this couldn't be used for other move modifiers, but here is what I did for the `CubicBezierCurveMoveModifier` in Andengine GLES2.

All it really does is capture the old `x,y` coordinates before it updates and then calculates the angle based on the new `x,y`.

*I added in a `rotationOffset` parameter because the sprite image I was working with was off by 90 degrees. Would have figured 0 degrees was the top of the sprite, but either my math is horribly wrong or 0 degrees is right of the image*

```
import org.andengine.entity.IEntity;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.CubicBezierCurveMoveModifier;
import org.andengine.util.math.MathUtils;
import org.andengine.util.modifier.ease.IEaseFunction;

public class CubicBezierCurveWithRotationModifier extends CubicBezierCurveMoveModifier {

    float rotationOffset = 0f;

    public CubicBezierCurveWithRotationModifier(float rotationOffset, float pDuration, float pX1, float pY1, float pX2, float pY2, float pX3, float pY3, float pX4, float pY4) {
        super(pDuration, pX1, pY1, pX2, pY2, pX3, pY3, pX4, pY4);
        this.rotationOffset = rotationOffset;
    }

    public CubicBezierCurveWithRotationModifier(float rotationOffset, float pDuration, float pX1, float pY1, float pX2, float pY2, float pX3, float pY3, float pX4, float pY4, IEaseFunction pEaseFunction) {
        super(pDuration, pX1, pY1, pX2, pY2, pX3, pY3, pX4, pY4, pEaseFunction);
        this.rotationOffset = rotationOffset;
    }

    public CubicBezierCurveWithRotationModifier(float rotationOffset, float pDuration, float pX1, float pY1, float pX2, float pY2, float pX3, float pY3, float pX4, float pY4, IEntityModifierListener pEntityModifierListener) {
        super(pDuration, pX1, pY1, pX2, pY2, pX3, pY3, pX4, pY4, pEntityModifierListener);
        this.rotationOffset = rotationOffset;
    }

    public CubicBezierCurveWithRotationModifier(float rotationOffset, float pDuration, float pX1, float pY1, float pX2, float pY2, float pX3, float pY3, float pX4, float pY4, IEntityModifierListener pEntityModifierListener, IEaseFunction pEaseFunction) {
        super(pDuration, pX1, pY1, pX2, pY2, pX3, pY3, pX4, pY4, pEntityModifierListener, pEaseFunction);
        this.rotationOffset = rotationOffset;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed, IEntity pEntity) {
        float oldX = pEntity.getX();
        float oldY = pEntity.getY();

        super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed, pEntity);

        float deltaX = pEntity.getX() - oldX;
        float deltaY = pEntity.getY() - oldY;

        float degree = (float) Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);

        pEntity.setRotation(rotationOffset + MathUtils.radToDeg(degree));
    }
}
```